# How to load a webpage faster when fetching more then 1000 results from mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

When i am filtering mysql results using php programming, the webpage is taking too much time to load (approx 30-40 secs) when results are getting more than 1000. How can i reduce the loading time to as minimum as i can ?

Comment: I am using join queries

Comment: Joins obviously slows the query

Comment: @HarshitShrivastava Thats not true at all. In fact, if the table is big it actually speeds up the query in most cases since it doesn't have to look through as much data

Comment: @Crecket yes you are right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about using [views](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-view.html)? The view will be updated and have the latest data. Then you `select *` from the view rather than joining on the original table.

As per other answers, indexing on the fields you use for filtering and joining should speed up the process. These are also nice to have when you are using views (they will update faster).

Finally, try to do everything in the database, ie do not loop the results in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

If your query use a WHERE clause, you might want to index your table on the columns used as WHERE criteria to allow faster retrieval.

[Learn more about it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1108/how-does-database-indexing-work).

Comment: Yes i am using WHERE clause in my query, so can you add a simple indexing example of query ?

Comment: Will that reduce the time to minimum ?

Comment: if not to minimum, it will definitely reduce.

Comment: @KillerHacker added a link to an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

If you want only limited results (that can save time), then use

```
select * from table as RANDOM LIMIT 500
```